# Firewalld, opening all subnet for zone

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables, firewalld

Another question about firewalld, I need someone to explain this to me in simple words, because I read countless posts and I don't know what's happening here.

I've enable the `home` zone in NetworkManager:
[image]

And here's what I have configured in firewalld:

```
root@torann:~# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public

root@torann:~# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
docker
  interfaces: docker0
home
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources: 172.20.12.0/24
public
  interfaces: tun0 tun1 tun2 tun3 ppp0

root@torann:~# firewall-cmd --zone=home --list-all
home (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources: 172.20.12.0/24
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

root@torann:~# netstat -nlap|grep kdeconnect
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN      1332/kdeconnectd    
udp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                                1332/kdeconnectd    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16007    1332/kdeconnectd     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19657    1332/kdeconnectd     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     24604    1332/kdeconnectd     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16926    1332/kdeconnectd     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     16925    1332/kdeconnectd     

root@torann:~# iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

So why are my ports not open?

Shouldn't the entire subnet be allowed for any port?

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks

Comment: Please paste `nft list ruleset` as well

Comment: Also, apparently the target `default` is *similar* to `reject`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64428762

Comment: So instead I should create my own zones "custom-home" "custom-office", set the target to "ACCEPT", add the relevant subnets to each of them, and then configure NetworkManager to enable to relevant zone depending where I am??